# OpenID vs OAuth

Tags: oauth, openid

I keep hearing OpenID is for federated authentication where as OAuth is for delegated authorization. Is OpenID just the initial step of OAuth involving a redirect to the identity server ? If so why cannot I use OAuth for authentication ?

Answer (score 1):

Open id and Oauth are two different things.

[OpenID](http://openid.net/) is about authentication (ie. proving who you are), [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) is about authorization (ex. I grant your application access to my Google drive account.  When your application is accessing my drive account there is no guarantee that it is me preforming the action.).

OAuth is often used in external sites to allow access to protected data without them having to re-authenticate a user.

> If so why cannot I use OAuth for authentication ?

Because Oauth knows nothing about who is preforming the task. It could be an application running in the background.